# Which of these two is an inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I have a simple question on which am seeking help clarifying. Am looking at two inner products, one which my text says is an inner product and I find it to be not, and another my text says it is but I find it to be not.

$$a_1b_1 + a_2b_1 + a_1b_2 + 2a_2b_2$$
which I put in matrix form as

$$(a_1,a_2)
 \left(\begin{matrix}
   1 & 1\\
   1 & 2
 \end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \end{matrix}\right)
$$
The matrix of coefficients is symmetric so I expect properties of inner products are satisfied. Next I have to show the matrix is positive definite. When I put it in upper triangular form

```
row2->row2-row1
```

I find the pivots are positive,
$$
 \left(\begin{matrix}
    1 &-1 \\
    0 & 1
 \end{matrix}\right)
$$

hence the matrix is positive definite, hence the last property is satisfied
but my textbook says it is not an inner product.
The other function

$$a_1b_1+a_2b_1+a_1b_2-a_2b_2$$

$$(a_1,a_2)
 \left(\begin{matrix}
   1 & 1\\
   1 & -1
 \end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \end{matrix}\right)
$$
whose matrix I find to be negative definite

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
   1 & 1\\
   0 & -2
 \end{matrix}\right)$$

but my text says it is an inner product.

Comment: Your first expression contains twice a2b1 is this an error or actually like this? In any case your matrix is also wrong. And one does not determine pos def by rowreduction.

Comment: Sorry it is an error, it is supposed to be a2b1+a1b2. Then how does one determine positive definiteness?

Comment: So with all $+$ signs in the first product instead of $-$, is that the correct formula now?

Comment: To decide pos def you can for example determine the eigenvalues. If they are all positive it is pos def, if not then not. For the second it is not. For the first, as written now, it is.

Comment: Thanks @quid from now on I will use the eigenvalues for testing positive definiteness

Comment: Sylvester's criterion is another way to test real symmetric matrices for positive definiteness: an $n \times n$ matrix is positive definite if and only if the upper-left $k \times k$ submatrix has positive determinant for each $k=1,\dots, n$. In practice, these determinants can be tested for positivity by progressively row-reducing the matrix to upper-triangular form, and this leads to the criterion which you correctly used, based on the positivity of the pivots. (For this to work, one cannot just do any kind of row reduction; we restrict to adding multiples of higher rows to lower rows.)

Comment: Thanks @Brent Kerby, I was just in the process of posting a comment on why row reducing does not work, then I saw your comment. Now it is clear. I am beginning to think my 66 years age is limiting my ability to solve simple problems. I was tteaching mathematics 15 years ago, now am rying to relearn. One simple problem am stuck with is a matrix with columns (1 -1), (-1 3). My text suggests a diagonal matrix with the diagonal (1 2) which should be the eigenvectors. But am finding eigenvectors which are both positive (2+-root(2) but not 1,2. Any help?

Comment: Sorry I meant eigenvalues not eigenvectors.